# How to use Azure Authorization social providers with a static html angular website?

Tags: angular, azure, google-signin, azure-authentication

I have followed this documentation on how to use the azure social authorization provider for google plus sign-in. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication

After authentication is finished it sends the app to this page: https://yourapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done

Is the post_login_redirect_url a way to redirect back to your web application and pass the token?

Is there anyway to redirect back to your static html website with the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more into the post_login_redirect_url it looks like the way is that this parameter is attached like this /.auth/login/?post_login_redirect_url=/

You can then grab the token from your url as it is stored in the hash value.

This question was helpful: [How to set Azure Authentication custom login return url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348271/how-to-set-azure-authentication-custom-login-return-url)

Another way to get the token that I found was to call /.auth/me to get back your authorized array of tokens.