# Azure App Service https only - wrong redirect with authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, redirect, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I successfully host an app service on azure (ASP.Net MVC 5). There are some areas that are publically accessible (*...mywebsite*). To access the admin area (*...mywebsite/admin*) a user needs needs to authorize which is done via *Azure AD* and the `[Authorize]` attribute on all controller actions.
Everything worked perfectly via http.

Now in Azure I added a certificate to the app service and enabled *„always use https“* which means every user accessing the app service via http gets redirected to https (http://mywebsite -> https://mywebsite).
Fine, it also works. But: when I try to access the admin area, after the login page from Microsoft where I enter my username and pwd it doesn’t get redirected to https://mywebsite/admin (which I expected) but back to the base url https://mywebsite.
Seems that I am missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be due to your web application's Azure AD registration containing the https://mywebsite/ as the Return URL and not the https://mywebsite/admin. You can either add your admin site as another return URL or use some code to determine the location to return to after login. See [How to set Azure Authentication custom login return url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348271/how-to-set-azure-authentication-custom-login-return-url)

Comment: Thanks. After changing the return URL it worked like a charm!